# How to become administrator again

Tags: 11.10, permissions, root, users, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Well I was messing around with the user accounts and I noticed that my account was listed under "administrator".

I knew that wasn't right, since I had to use Sudo to install stuff and get root privileges, so I unlocked user accounts and set my account from "Administrator" to "standard".

Then I changed my mind and wanted to keep "Administrator", even if I had to use sudo. So I unlocked it again (I stupidly went to sound settings or something, then went back), but it didn't accept my password.

So now that is messed up. I also can not install software, and probably can't do anything else root can.
So my question is this: Is there any way to get my account back to administrator?

Comment: It's probably worth explicitly stating what I'm sure you've realized by now. "Administrator" means different things in different operating systems. In Windows, an Administrator has full privileges all the time. In Ubuntu, an Administrator has the privilege to ask for root-execution through sudo. Put another way, Ubuntu (by default) uses membership in the admin group to control who can access root privileges.