# I am no longer in sudoers?

Tags: 11.10, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

```
jiewmeng is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Whats happening? Its a home PC with me as the only user. I noticed this only happended recently. Perhaps after some recent update. I was running `sudo add-apt-repository ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems unlikely that just adding a repository would have removed you from `sudoers` (or more likely, the `admin` group).

#### Are you still in the admin group?

Simply run `groups` from a terminal. You should see a list come out. You're looking for the word `admin`. If that's in there, this isn't your issue.

The easiest way to restore your `sudo` rights is to reboot in recovery mode (hold left-shift at boot, select a recovery mode kernel, boot to the root prompt). Once in there you might be able to run (swap `oli` for your username) :

```
adduser oli admin
```

But I've seen some thing that suggest this might not work from a recovery console. Try it. If that doesn't work, or you want to check, run `nano /etc/group`

Look for the admin group and add your username to the end, like so:

```
admin:x:115:oli
```

You should then be able to reboot and be in the right group.

#### Has something melted `/etc/sudoers`?

Unfortunately you can't read `/etc/sudoers` unless you're root. So back to recovery mode (as above). Once you're in there run `nano /etc/sudoers`. You're looking for a pair of lines like this:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

If that's there, this isn't your problem. If it's commented out or missing, whack it back in there!

Comment: I don't mean adding repository removed me from sudoers, I think it was actually an update or perhaps I did something wrong. Ok I boot into recovery mode later, but I'd mark this as correct 1st. It looks right

Comment: I did something similar a while back.  The other trick to know which Oli doesn't have here is that when you use recovery mode, the hard disk is mounted in read-only mode.  You'll have to remount it read/write before running adduser or nano/vi/etc.  This is how I got out of it:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user

Comment: I found I cannot login to root, it says wrong password. But I used the same password, when I was installing ubuntu ...

Comment: jiewmeng - I'm in the same boat. I actually recorded my password somewhere else, so the fact that I can't login as root is... not good.

Comment: In addition to my last comment, I should add that I'm using an image of Ubuntu 11.10 with VirtualBox under Windows 7. If I revert to a previous snapshot, I can suddenly use sudo again, although I still can't login to root with any of my known passwords. I can confirm that groups shows admin on the good image for my sudo user, but gets removed after the reboot. If you are suffering from the same symptoms, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user

Comment: @AaronNewton Yes, per Stéphane's comment from a couple of months ago, you need to remount the root drive in read/write mode.

Comment: @Oli thank you for the feedback. Fortunately in my case I had that good snapshot. I restored this, ran "sudo adduser my-user admin" and also set a root password for good measure. After this, I got a clean reboot and I can sudo with my user.