# How do I restore admin access?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

I'm thinking that I've lost su/root access to my system but wanted to throw this question out to see if there was any hope left.
My own personal account was the first to be created upon installing Ubuntu and this the only Administrator. A few other accounts were created but as standard users.
The system was to be given to one user and all other users removed including my own account. I thus removed everyone from the system except the user that was going to own the system nor my own (because I was logged on). So under the other account, I was going to attempt removing my own "administrator" account and make the remaining user the admin.
I did something horribly wrong which was demote myself to standard user, and then now obviously, cannot not not only remove my own account, but make the remaining user the admin. I tried a few things like going to recovery mode, looking for info on how to reset root password... but nothing. Any ideas?