# How to change my account type from standard to administrator?

Tags: 11.10, users, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

I just re-installed my Ubuntu 11.10, and I accidently changed my account type from admin to standard and I don't have a second admin account to change it back.

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user

Answer (score -1):

Boot into recovery modus. There you have superuser rights to change it back.

```
adduser Yngthlet admin
```

Exit and proceed.

Comment: You don't explain the user how to boot in to recovery mode, you don't explain which option he has to select on the recovery mode menu, you don't explain how to mount his disk to be writable (by default in 11.10 its not) and you don't explain what the command does or if `Yngthlet` is (maybe the username on his / her's system is not that?). Hope this helps!