# I deleted my original user account. The new account has no password. How can I enable it?

Tags: permissions, users, password-recovery, username

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

How can enable my admin account? i deleted the other one and now the new one is without password and i cant access it and cant do anything with my guest account.

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion is based on a previous answer. It assumes you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

1. Boot your computer to the GRUB boot menu. If necessary, press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key immediately after booting starts to force the GRUB menu to be displayed.
2. Select an entry which will boot into `recovery mode`.
3. The text graphics menu shown in the image below should appear. Use the <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> arrow key to select an entry.

   - Select `root (Drop to root shell prompt)` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

     [image: recovery menu with <code>root</code> entry selected]
4. The system is currently mounted as read only. Enter the command below to remount your file system as read/write. This allows you to make changes.
   `mount -o remount,rw /`
5. In your question you said you created a new username which does not have a password. Since I do not know what that new username is, I will use `REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME` to refer to it. Please replace `REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME` with your new username which is not working in the commands below.
6. Choose and create a password for this username with the command below.
   `passwd REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME`
7. Use the command below to list all the groups this username is currently a member of.
   `groups REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME`
8. If step (7) shows that the username is a member of the `nopasswdlogin` group, use the command below to remove it from this group.
   `gpasswd --delete REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME nopasswdlogin`
9. In the unlikely event that you do ***not*** see the username itself listed in the output from the `groups` command in step (7), use the command below to add it and make it the primary login group for this username.

   `usermod -g REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME`

   *Note:* Yes, the username is repeated twice. For example, if the username were `joeuser`  the command would be `usermod -g joeuser joeuser`
10. Use the command below to ensure the username is in all the default groups it should be. *Note:* Do *not* add spaces between the commas (`,`)

    `usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare REPLACE-WITH-USERNAME`
11. Repeat the `groups` command in step (7) to verify that the username was correctly added to the groups.
12. Restart your system with the command below. (It can take a few seconds. Wait for it ...)
    `reboot`
13. Login using the password you chose for the username in step (6).

    - I suggest also trying, for example, `sudo fdisk -l` to verify that `sudo` is working for you correctly.
    - I would also retry the `groups` command from step (7) to verify one last time that the username is a member of the groups it should be in. (Better safe than sorry, no?)

Comment: The admin account isn't called sudo; it's called root. The `sudo` command allows commands to be executed with root privileges. It is **impossible** to know the root password - (Techy bit - the password hash stored in `/etc/shadow` begins with !, and there is no possible value which can be hashed to get that output)