# Administrator account changed to Standard

Tags: sudo

I just discovered when I wanted to install a package that my Administrator account has changed to a Standard account and I don't have access to `sudo`. There is no other user account except my account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I changed my account from Administrator to Standard. How can I reverse this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150903/i-changed-my-account-from-administrator-to-standard-how-can-i-reverse-this) and [How can I re-instate my admin privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179462/how-can-i-re-instate-my-admin-privileges).