# How can I add my user to the sudo list?

Tags: sudo, administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04, Now I am using standard user, but I want to change my user to admin when I got the following error(link only) I am not able to paste the picture.

[image]
This has been coming from terminal(model image)

[image]

And I am also not able to open the disk.
Please give me an idea of how to solve this problem, which will be very useful for me.

Thanks in advance