# I accidentally deleted administrator account and the other accounts are asking root password

Tags: users, password-recovery, administration

I unexpectedly deleted my user account (the only administrator for the machine). I have another account which is a standard account and now I can't access my hard disk or anything with that standard account - it is asking for the root password. Is there any way I can recover access to the administrator account?

Comment: Related: [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) I'm not sure if we should consider this a duplicate. Probably not, since this has answers about how to *create a new account* (and that's about how to make an existing account an administrator account).

Answer (score 10):

You can use recovery mode to add the standard user to the admin group (which is now called sudo in 12.04). Below is a set of simple instructions copied from [my personal website](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/deletedadmin.html).

### Using Recovery Mode To Add Users To The Admin / Sudo Group

First shutdown your computer.

Then `restart whilst holding shift` on the keyboard to load grub menu.

Select `recovery mode` from the grub menu.

Select `drop to root shell` from the recovery menu.

Use the following command to remount the drive `mount -o rw,remount /`

Now type `adduser username sudo` replacing username with your user name  ie. 'adduser  phil sudo'

You should now see a message saying 'adding user' followed by 'done'.

Type `shutdown -r now` to restart the computer.

EDIT: If it is telling you that user xxx does not exist, first you can use the following command to list users and make sure that you have the correct username

```
ls /home
```

The other option is add a new user, from recovery mode using the following commands :

```
useradd username -m -s /bin/bash  
passwd username
adduser username sudo
```

Again replacing `username` with your desired username.

Comment: whilie in adduser comand it is showing user XXX does'nt exist please help me.

Comment: @Niranjan  - I have edited the answer to include the information you need. :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recovery console and boot as root this is a extra option on your grub menu and create a new user then add them to the admin group.  I'm not sure if this will fix your issue, but give it a try and let me know.

```
useradd newuser
adduser newuser admin
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem 
Select recovery mode (if you are using laptop it differents but it's in the same place you get in bios)
Then select root 
Write the command(# adduser )
Then the command(# password root)
And write the new password
And restart by the command( #reboot)

Comment: this is a bad idea. The root account is disabled in Ubuntu for security/safety reasons

Comment: I have a problem now I loved in but I can't use mu computer normally can you help me

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Can you say more clearly?