# How can I create an infinite login loop for a specific user?

Tags: login

Well I know the question is weird, but i have a user "Bob" and I want only bob's account to be stuck in infinite login loop. Please note I don't want to get out of a login loop..I want this particular user to be stuck in infinite login loop.

How do I do this?

Comment: The OP only wanted the user Bob to go into infinite login loop. It is obvious he is concerned with GUI login screen, thus changing permissions/ownership of .Xauthority is enough

Comment: Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: Please review http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/conduct

Comment: I think this should a stack exchange site "How to mess with your coworkers"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Execute this command in terminal.

```
chown -R root:root /home/Bob/.Xauthority
```

This command with change ownership of .Xauthority directory of Bob user to root user thus not allowing Bob to login.

Comment: The user can still log in via other means, ssh or kerberos to name a few. Set the users shell to /bin/false , that will prevent login.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've addressed that

Comment: Restart your system? This isn't Windows were talking about!

Comment: Reboot your system? This isn't Windows we're talking about!

Comment: +4 -2 on this answer? Can please i know why downvotes, If downvote is genuine then leave comment (why?)

Comment: What is wrong with the sentence "rebooting or restarting your system" . How does it make sense that it should be used for windows only.Check the second answer of this post , he has used the same sentence. http://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-restart-shutdown-from-a-terminal

Comment: Then finally remove the prompt to restart the system. No restart is required.

Comment: You already got the comments explaining the downvotes. One issue, the superfluous reboot, has been fixed by A.B.'s edit. (Unlike Windows users, many Linux users care about uptime. Unnecessary reboots are considered bad advice — and reboots are rarely necessary.) The second issue, that this answer only prevents X session logins, in an easily circumventable way, is a fatal flaw with this answer. The user can still log in through a text console (Ctrl-Alt-F1). Once logged in, Bob can `rm .Xauthority`, even though the file is owned by root. Then your entire solution is defeated.

Comment: @200_success the user can login via other tty , are you sure about it? have you tried it? Anyways it cannot be denied that serg's answer is better, i've already upvoted for that answer and i did upvote bodhi.zazen's comments  too.

Comment: Not only can Bob log in using a text console, he can also login via SSH, if an SSH server is running. It's not a matter of other answers being better; this solution is _totally insecure_ and bad advice.

Comment: Yes,  whenever my .Xauthority gets corrupt and who-knows-why becomes owned by root, I fix it by logging into tty2 and chowning it back to my group and user names. I am skeptical of `rm file owned by root` part of the comments and `unnecessary reboots` ,though.  Unless the user is in the sudo group,  which then makes sense.

Comment: @Serg The ability to remove a file is determined by the permissions of the directory that contains it, not by the permissions on the file being removed.

Comment: Ah ok. So if I have a folder owned by me , another user wouldn't be able to remove a file in it , even if that user owns the file , is that right ?

Comment: @Serg A user can delete a file in an ordinary, non-sticky directory if and only if they have write access on the directory. This happens if they own the directory and it's user-writeable (if not, they may `chmod u+w` it, as they own it). But it also happens if they're in a group-writeable directory's group owner, the directory is other-writeable (o+w), or [an ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) lets them write to it. [Here's a basic example.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10824568/) [*But sticky directories observe different rules.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

Answer (score 12):

To address bodhi's comment that the user can login through other means, open the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` and at the bottom add the following line

```
username hard maxlogins 0
```

The user will be able to login in tty but will be kicked out immediatelly, and lightdm (or any other login manager for that matter) will do the same. For good measure I would use this together with chowning .Xauthority

Answer (score 6):

Change the shell for Bob:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/false Bob
```

Comment: This is the normal way. Due to the way xlogin works it still invokes the shell so it still fails out.

Comment: Please read this: [SSH Security and You - /bin/false is *not* security](http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/ssh-security/)

Comment: What does security have to do with this question, which the OP has asked?

Answer (score -1):

If the purpose is to prevent login of the user Bob, I suggest you can also lock the user password and expire his account using:

```
passwd -l bob
usermod --expiredate 1 bob
```

This blocks also ssh login with keys. There is more info in [how to enable or disable an user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282806/how-to-enable-or-disable-a-user) question.