# How to suspend particular user in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, suspend, users

I searched but could not find how to suspend particular user in Ubuntu 12.04. I found the following option:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

However suspend the current user. I want root user to suspend another user. How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As root we can kill all processes of a user with:

```
sudo pkill -u <username>
```

After that lightdm will present the login screen.

Note that this will immediately terminate all applications a user had run. Unsaved data will therefore be lost.

To disable a user account see [How to enable or disable a user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282806/how-to-enable-or-disable-a-user)

Comment: This means that instead of suspend do disabled? I also want to ask if you disabled all processes are killed automatically ?

Comment: I wanted to ask when I make a disabled user. Unless disabled and suspend are the same ?

Comment: Disabled = the user can no longer log in. Suspend = the computer is in powersafe suspend-to-ram-state. Pkill = a logged in user is logged out, and all their processes incl. running applications are terminated.