# How to disable user's login without disabling the account?

Tags: 14.04, login

I have already gone through the [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19333/disable-a-users-login-without-disabling-the-account) in Unix & Linux and tried altering `/etc/passwd` manually like below

```
user1:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/user1:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

after making change `user1` is not being able to login from terminal but surprisingly can login from `gnome`

What's wrong?

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
kernel:         3.19.0-33-generic
```

Comment: Technically your question is a duplicate, there have been questions asking same thing before. I do recall posting answer to exactly similar question. You could [refer to this](http://askubuntu.com/q/282806/295286). Yes, it says lock/disable account, but essentially it's the same thing. User will be there, just unable to log in.  I'll be searching for the question I mentioned earlier, however

Answer (score 2):

```
passwd -l
```

that might be what you're looking for :)

from the passwd man page:

> -l, --lock Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no
>   possible encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the
>   password).
>
> Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be
>   able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key). To
>   disable the account, administrators should use usermod
>   --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
> Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.

Comment: What does that do exactly? Can you add a small description of what this will actually accomplish.

Comment: Thanks CZ0 but I was aware of this solution as I gone through the post in Unix & Linux channel. I was more keen to know that how come after changing the shell to `/sbin/nologin` user is being able to login. 
`chown -R root:root /home/user1/.Xauthority` answered that.

Comment: That's simply because when you log in via the GUI, you're not spawning a shell.