# On each sudo command I get [sudo] password for root:

Tags: password, sudo, root, password-recovery

I have run a script https://github.com/starlilyth/Linux-PoolManager to install it and I have run into the situation where on each `sudo` command I get the prompt:

```
[sudo] password for root:
```

the `/etc/sudoers` looks like this now :

```
-r--r----- 1 root root 823 mar  7 16:07 /etc/sudoers
```

And I cannot access it.

What can I do now to restore the system to normal functionality ?

**EDIT**

```
$grep sudo /etc/group
 sudo:x:27:USERNAME
```

Comment: `/etc/sudoers` is a file, not a directory. You can check it with `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` and modify it with `sudo visudo`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the permissions of your `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: @Jobin it says read, and if read is all he can how can he use `sudo visudo` to fix things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sudoers file is default like this:

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults    env_reset

# Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to not need a password
# %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

This does not contain your user so to be able to use sudo add this:

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

That will grant you sudo-access. (If its the best way to do it I'm not sure, but it works for me when I install Debian)

Also, take a look at this community documentation for more information:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

Comment: Check my edit - I do not have access to `/etc/sudoers`.....

Comment: Then I am at loss. Have you tried through the recovery console?

Answer (score 3):

Use the instructions on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/161091/25863) to access a recovery shell.

Once you have your file system mounted with write support just move the file `/etc/sudoers` to another place and restore the original configuration with `apt-get install sudo`.

Also, if you do not remember the password for your user you can take the chance and use the command `passwd yourusername` to change it on the recovery shell.