# How to fix admin account file permissions after I deleted and restored it?

Tags: permissions

I deleted my administrator account and restored it using an answer I found from this post (link below).

[I accidentally deleted administrator account and the other accounts are asking root password](https://askubuntu.com/q/161074/1497964)

So everything got restored...but I must have done something wrong because I got both accounts back but my original admin account had a new user ID and belonged to the group of my second one, which had the ID I had before.

Can I fix this by changing file permissions for the whole / file system?

And if so what are the default permissions? I don't wanna mess anything up...again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the permissions of the files

```
 chown -R user:group /path_directory
```

I suggest you, if there is only change in user ID then change the user ID of your new admin account to the old id:

```
usermod --uid [new UID for the user account]  USERNAME
```

Comment: chown worked for me for the file permissions, but I was unable to change the uid because it all ready existed, but this seems to have solved my main issue.