# How can I re-instate my admin privileges?

Tags: boot, grub2, sudo, administrator

I am running 12.04 LTS. It's a pretty default installation and is the only OS on this machine.

I have two users one has administrator rights the other does not.
I accidentally removed administrator rights from the "admin" user.

I tried to [add myself back as a sudo user](https://askubuntu.com/a/70445/85096) but that requires reaching GRUB during boot but I cannot get there because my `/etc/default/grub` has `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and changing that to a positive integer requires admin privileges to save the changes and run `sudo update-grub`.

Should I boot from LiveCD?
The [Reasons for Using a LiveCD Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) discouraged my a bit.
Right now all I have handy is an install DVD from 11.10, but that did not help me much.

Not sure what to do now.

Any suggestions?

NOTE:
12.04 does not have an `admin` group and I have not enabled `root`

Comment: Press the SHIFT key down during boot-up to force the GRUB menu to display.

Answer (score 5):

Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> right after BIOS posts.  That should get you into the GRUB menu regardless of whether your `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` is set to zero or not.

From the GRUB menu, select your most recent kernel tagged with "(recovery mode)".  Once that finishes loading, you should be presented with a menu that has an option to "drop to root shell prompt".  You might have to arrow-down to see it.

[image: recovery menu]

That should get you to the command line as the root user.  From there you should be able to re-add yourself as a sudo user.  Note that you might have a read-only filesystem at that point.  If so, run the below command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: FWIW, my own answer from 6 years ago just saved me.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo adduser my_user_name admin` will add an existing user called my_user_name into the admin group.

`sudo adduser new_user_name will` add a new user

`sudo adduser my_user_name root` will add an existing user called my_user_name into the  root group.

Once you can load Ubuntu and get into the Desktop you can download an application for modifying users rights and groups. Open a Terminal and type:

**sudo apt-get install users-admin**

Comment: I tried this on my 12.04 VM, and it said that the admin group did not exist.  Is this possibly the "adm" group instead?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 no, you would need the group `sudo`.