# Default Ubuntu Server Credentials?

Tags: server

I'm running Ubuntu server through VMPlayer but I don't know, nor can find the login credentials.

Can some one let me know please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it has GRUB then select recovery mode. You should have a root shell. Look up adding users.

If you want to set a root password run `passwd root`

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't any "default login credentials", so it sounds like you'll need to create a user for yourself.  To accomplish this, you'll need to boot into recovery mode (as acematrix mentioned).  Here's a link to a question/answer that describes how to do that: [How can I re-instate my admin privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179462/how-can-i-re-instate-my-admin-privileges/179475#179475)

With VMWare/Player it's a little tricky.  You'll need to start it and then quick give the Ubuntu VM focus and hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> before it boots.  Follow the instructions in the question linked above, and invoke "recovery mode."

Once you're in, you'll want to add yourself as a user:

```
adduser new_user_name
```

Give it a password and provide any other info asked.

```
Adding user `new_user_name' ...
Adding new group `new_user_name' (1001) ...
Adding new user `new_user_name' (1001) with group `new_user_name' ...
Creating home directory `/home/new_user_name' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for new_user_name
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: tester
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
```

Then, add this user to the admin and sudo groups (assuming that you want your user to have the ability to "sudo").

```
adduser new_user_name admin
addgroup new_user_name sudo
```

Then reboot and login as your new user.