# How do i find my username when locked out

Tags: login

How do i find out what my username is when I am locked out of my computer? I forgot what my username is and it won't let me pass the user login page.

Comment: Try "root" :) If that does not help, boot from a CD or USB stick, and check `/etc/passwd` on the system disc.

Comment: Boot with live usb or cd you installed with. Open file manager. View your hard drive. open home folder. You will have a sub-folder for storing your files. the same sub-folder is your username. Probably something like `tamara`.

Comment: If you haven't live usb or cd, then boot in rescue mode, get the root shell and run `ls /home`. You'll see all usernames allowed to login.

Answer (score 2):

Get to root shell as described [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/179475/449979)
Run following command to find user(subfolders are usernames): `ls /home`
`reboot` and login with one of usernames find at above step