# Problem with root password, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, root, password-recovery

Couple of hours earlier I installed the drivers of a HP DeskJet 3000, which I found here: http://hplipopensource.com/.

Since that moment I cannot install anything from the Ubuntu Software Centre. It seems that my root password is wrong now. But I haven't changed it! I have no problem log in to my profile, using my ordinary, very first password I have set when I installed Ubuntu, but when I need to use it as a root password, it is simply does not work...

Any ideas how to fix the mess?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not have a root password. What your being asked for in software center is your password. Check your caps lock, etc. and try again.

Failing that reset your password from the terminal with `passwd`

And if that doesn't work, run `sudo ls` from the terminal and see if your allowed to sudo.

Comment: Hello again, I have tried passwd , it changed my password successfully but the issue still remains. With sudo sl , states the following: *******(name of the user) is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user