# I am not in "sudoers" even though I am only user

Tags: 12.04

Using Ubuntu 12.04
The only thing I have done recently is add my name to "dialout" to enable communication to an Arduino board vis USB. After that my user name and password are no longer recognized for sudo operations. I am the only user and I always booted without need of password. I need to correct this situation.
I tried rebooting in safe mode but that did not correct the problem. The safe boot wanted to download 160 MB to which I declined until I am again a sudoer. The user accounts lists me as "standard" even though I have done sudo ops before.

SOLVED: Since I could not do any sudo ops because I was locked out I used this link to add myself back into the sudo group;
[How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)