# How to modify and give acces to user in sudo file

Tags: sudo

when I am trying to install vim using `sudo apt-get install vim`, its showing sudoers file error. Please help me out.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: when iam trying to install any software for eg :vim or any tng , its showing user not in the sudoers file, this incident will be reported

Comment: Try this: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user

Comment: And do you know any software for ubuntu like network magic in windows. i want to track my users and screen shots of their browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you had `sudo` rights but lost it, then [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user?lq=1) should help you.

If you want to grant `sudo` rights to new users, you might add them to `sudo` group by issuing

```
sudo adduser USERNAME sudo
```

That user will have to log out and log in again though.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) you have Ubuntu community documentation on `sudoers` file, if you want some more complicated setup.