# Can't login as root

Tags: login, password, sudo

My user is removed from the sudoers file. I don't how it got removed because i only have access to my machine. I tried accessing the sudoers file but it mentions my username and asks the password for it like "[sudo] password for arunn:". But it doesn't accepts the password which i normally use to login to my machine and i hve no problem in it. The problem is when i try to use sudo and gives the error when i give the password and the error message as follows "arunn is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported". Also i recently added my user name to my virtualbox and will that be the problem ? Please i'm in terriblle situation so help please !

Comment: See [How do I add myself back as a sudo user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pkexec` even if you are not in `sudoers`. Do:

```
pkexec visudo
```

and add back an entry for your username. `pkexec` will accept your password since PolicyKit authorization is configured elsewhere, and is probably untouched by whatever messed with `sudoers`.

Comment: I suspect this won't work. Ubuntu's default config gives both `sudo` and polkit based powers to `sudo` group members (or `admin` group, in old versions of Ubuntu). Unless `sudoers` was *also* edited to remove the rule about that group, most likely the OP here has simply lost membership in the `sudo` group. And in that case, `pkexec` won't grant access. On the other hand, if the OP is not a member of those groups but just had a user line in `sudoers`, then (since, as you say, `sudoers` doesn't confer polkit powers) they probably cannot and *never could* run commands as root with `pkexec`.

Comment: @EliahKagan Hmmm. When he says he added his username to VirtualBox, perhaps he was adding his user to a group and forgot to add the append flag to `usermod`, instead of using `adduser`? True. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: Actually you might want to keep this answer around. If this question's duplicate status is correct, I think this answer will most likely not help. But if the duplicate status is not correct and fixing this isn't a matter of adding the user to a group... then this answer might help, or point the OP in the right direction.