# Sorry, user is not allowed to execute X as root on lt

Tags: bash, sudo, visudo

Whenever I try to run a command from the termainal as sudo, I am now getting the error:

**Sorry, user {user} is not allowed to execute {command} as root on lt.**

lt is the name of my computer.

The only thing I have done recently is add myself to a user group, which I have undone, but the error persists.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: *How* did you add + remove yourself from the user group? What is the output of the `id` command for your user?

Comment: The id command gives: uid=1000(d) gid=1000(d) groups=1000(d),33(www-data)

Comment: You need to add your user back to the sudo group - see [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: Thanks, that op's post contains a command like the one I entered. If you post in the answer I'll accept it.