# Locked my self out my original account and don't want to reinstall

Tags: root, lock

Was locking down root with the `/etc/grub/00.header` command and didn't know to finish it so I rebooted the computer and now I can't get into my `sudo` account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily undone. Boot into recovery mode using grub, and get to a terminal. Then type in

```
sudo usermod -U <username>
```

Where (`<username>`) is your username. That should unlock your account.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to check that it worked, so anyone with this same problem can see this!