# Sudo access for an existing acount

Tags: sudo

I have an ubuntu account but i do not have sudo access, I did try `sudo usermod -a -G username` to give me `sudo` access but I am getting `username is not a sudoer file, this will be reported.`
To get a sudo access to an existing account what do I need to do ?

Comment: You should be able to use Ubuntu's *recovery mode* as described in this answer: [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/a/70445/178692)

Answer (score 3):

login with root user using

```
 su - root
```

then run command

```
usermod -a -G sudo username
```

or

run command `visudo`
and paste

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

if still you face problem then run command

```
 mount -o rw,remount /
```

and try again above method

also, you are saying. you able to run command

```
sudo adduser chauhan sudo
```

then you can do this way also

```
su - chauhan
sudo usermod -a -G sudo username
```

Comment: Since I do not have sudo access I can not login root ! I am asking about existing account @pl_rock

Comment: yes I know , I did groups username and I can not see sudo access.

Comment: yes that was not working now i am in recovery mode and loged in to root, I tried usermod -a -G sudo username and I am getting usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd try again.

Comment: mount -o remount,rw / worked out and after that sudo adduser chauhan sudo is also working fine

Comment: @Chauhan: could you delete your comments as well and don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-) plrock:** upvoted!