# sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, chmod

I get error message always when I work with `sudo` command.

It shows always `sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700`.

A while ago I changed the permission of `/var` folder to `777`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What command did you use to change /var permissions?

Comment: It seems like the directory `/var/lib/sudo` doesn't have the right permissions.

On my folder the permissions for this folder are:
drwxr-xr-x        root:root      /var/lib/sudo

So you could run:
`sudo chown root:root /var/lib/sudo` (just to make sure you have the right owner:group for the folder) and `sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/sudo` to fix the permissions

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo chown -R root:sudo /var/lib/sudo   
sudo chmod -R 700 /var/lib/sudo
```

If sudo still does not work, you'll have to fix it from a root shell from the GRUB menu by following the instructions from: [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user).

Answer (score 1):

"Writable by non-owner" means that the current permissions of `/var/lib/sudo` allow either the file's `group` group or the file's `other` group to write into the directory, whilst only the owner (root) should be able to do so.

Removing the write permission for the `group` group and for the `other` group (`chmod go-w /var/lib/sudo`) should suffice, however since the suggested permissions are `0700`, just go for those:

```
sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo
```

Comment: sudo permission properties showing:

owner: root
group :root

Comment: @SaifullahAlam Which "sudo" are you talking about? Anyway, have you tried my command? It should fix the problem.

Comment: i tried your both command. firstly tried : `sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo` then tried `sudo chmod go-w /var/lib/sudo`. have i try it from root(#)?

Comment: @SaifullahAlam No, just run `sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo` and nothing else. Then try to run `sudo` (for whatever purpose) again. The message should be gone.

Comment: sorry for disturbing. it not works. i tried.

Comment: @SaifullahAlam No problem. Please install `tree` by running `sudo apt-get install tree` and add the output of `sudo tree -a /var/lib/sudo` to your question, and drop me a comment here so I know that you updated your question, I think you need to fix something else as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was also face this problem , and I solve this problem. Open your terminal and run the command,

```
sudo chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/sudo
```

I hope your problem is solved now.