# I messed up permissions in home folder I can not login

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, policykit

Some time ago I had [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698779/i-can-not-login-to-gnome-cairodock-session-after-manually-installed-udev-system) problem and I found a workaround by issuing following command

```
  sudo chmod 777 /dev/dri/card0
```

and leaving me with [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/1240336) bug.

I have been struggling to fix it for a week. Today I ran

```
  groups $USER
```

it printed

```
  kenn : www-data wheel
```

I thought that it would be a good idea to add current user into other groups, so I ran

```
  sudo usermod -G adm,disk,mail,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,fuse,lpadmin,netdev,sambashare,debian-tor,wireshark  kenn
```

I logged out and logged in but it did nothing. So I wanted to revert changes I made and deleted groups I added to current user by

```
   sudo usermod -G www-data,wheel  kenn
```

it supposedly reverted the change, I checked again

```
   groups $USER
   kenn : www-data wheel
```

But when I logged out I could not log in.

I logged in and opened terminal but now I can not run command with sudo

I get `Sorry, user kenn is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/adduser as root on kenn`

How can I revert changes I caused?

How can I add current user to adm and sudo groups?

EDIT:
 I managed to add myself to `sudo` and `adm` group from `root` account. And then ran

```
  sudo usermod -aG adm,disk,mail,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,fuse,lpadmin,netdev,sambashare,debian-tor,wireshark  kenn
```

But I don't know which more ones to add

I still dont understand what I did wrong.

It must be related to `usermod -G` switch instead of `usermod -aG`

```
  id
```

returns

```
  uid=1000(kenn) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),4(adm),6(disk),8(mail),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),104(fuse),108(lpadmin),109(netdev),124(sambashare),129(debian-tor),148(wireshark),1010(wheel)
```

I need to know default groups that any admin account must have

Comment: It sounds like you messed up you usergroup membership(s), not your home folder permissions: start with [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) and we'll take things from there

Comment: @steeldriver
Thanks for the info. I managed to add myself to `sudo` and `adm` group from `root` account. And then run `sudo usermod -aG adm,disk,mail,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,fuse,lpadmin,netdev,sambashare,debian-tor,wireshark  kenn`
     But I don't know which more ones to add

Comment: That looks like plenty, unless you are having specific access problems? Is your primary group (usually the same as your username) intact? You can use the `id` command to check.

Comment: I added `id` output in my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Your home directory as well as the `.Xauthority` file both belong to your user `kenn`, however you've modified your user to belong only to `www-data wheel`.

My example (user is `xieerqi` ):

```
$ ls -ld /home/xieerqi
drwxr-xr-x 90 xieerqi xieerqi 16384 Dec 10 11:15 /home/xieerqi/

xieerqi:
$ ls -l .Xauthority                                                                           
-rw------- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 450 Dec 10 06:44 .Xauthority
```

What you need to do is to go into recovery mode (since you no longer belong to `sudo` group), enter root shell, remount filesystem with read write permissions (via `mount -o rw,remount /`), and run

```
usermod -a -G kenn,sudo,adm,dip,plugdev,lpadmin kenn
```

Additional info:

- [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92556/295286)

Comment: Serg thank you for your answer and the info.  I edited my question and provided more info. As I stated in edit section, I managed to login to root account and added `kenn` user to `adm,disk,mail,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,fuse,lpadmin,netdev,samb‌​ashare,debian-tor,wireshark` You also provided more groups. Aren't they enough to provide to fix privilege issue? Do I have go recovery mode and follow the steps you wrote for completeness?

Comment: Output of `ls -ld /home/kenn` is 

`drwxr-xr-x 387 kenn www-data 20480 Dec 10 20:13 /home/kenn`

Comment: @kenn adding yourself to groups should fix the permissions issue. Check the ownership of `.Xauthority` file in your home folder, make sure it belongs to your user. It's a frequent problem with GUI login, it may be at play as well.

Comment: `.Xauthority` seems to be ok. `ls -l .Xauthority 
-rw------- 1 kenn www-data 49 Dec 10 20:13 .Xauthority`

Comment: @kenn you have over 21 reputation, which means you can join the [AskUbuntu general chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) We can continue discussion there