# Please Help! Can't log into root Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, password, sudo

I am hoping someone can help me out here.  For some reason my system has stopped letting me sudo.  I can log into the machine just fine.  When I attempt to install a package or sudo -i, I get asked for my password then get told that my account is not part of the sudoers file.  There is only one user account on the machine.

I have attempted to use the recovery method off this site found here:
[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

When I try to change the password using Jorge's method I get an error:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error 
passwd: password unchanged

So I attempted the "drastic" measures:

mount -o remount,rw /
nano -B /etc/shadow

and deleted my encrypted password.  Saved the file and restarted the machine.

No password require, I hit return at the prompt.
But I still cannot go to sudo.  I tried sudo -i with the blank password and get:
Sorry try again...

So I used passwd to change my password.  It accepted the change.  I then tried sudo -i and again I got user not a member of the sudoers group!  I tried logging out and back in, it accepted my password to log in but not sudo -i or anything using sudo.

Please help me get my user back into the sudoers group.  Thanks (not feeling all that great but hopeful..)

Comment: Sounds like you needed [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) rather than a password reset

Comment: Yes, that is it, sorry new to Linux.  I am back in now.  Went to recovery and adduser <user> sudo and I am back in the group now!  not bad only wasted four hours, LOL

Comment: Thanks to all, had no idea how to ask the proper question...  I now know...