# No sudoers - what now?

Tags: sudo, password, root, default

I set up an administrator account for myself when I set up a new Ubuntu system. Somewhere along the line I did something wrong, and my account is now a standard account. I no longer have sudo privileges; when I try to use sudo, it asks for the root password rather than my password. I never set up a root password. Is there a default setting for that password? I can't fix anything without that password, because I need root access to make the fix.

My best guess is that what went wrong may have been due to the following sequence of events: I used `addgroup` to create a group named family. I used `adduser` to add an account for my wife, and `usermod` to put her in the family group. I then used `usermod` to put myself in the family group. Might I have accidentally removed myself from the sudoers list that way?

I needed two additional pieces of information to solve my problem:

1. By booting in recovery mode, and selecting "root" from the menu, I could operate as root without knowing root's password, even if logging in as root has been disabled by not giving it a password.
2. When booting in recovery mode, the root partition defaults to read-only mode. I needed to use `mount -rw -o remount /` in order to make it writable, before I could make any changes.

Comment: If you know your root password then you can add yourself in sudoers using visudo.

Comment: You can try to [boot into a root shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) and add yourself back in sudo.

Comment: I'm the one who installed Ubuntu on this machine, and I didn't set up a root passwd on it. The only way I'd be able to follow either of those suggestions would be if the root password has a default value. If so, could someone tell me what it is?

Comment: I successfully booted from the same USB drive I used for the installation. It automatically tried to mount the root partition (/dev/sdb1) as /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64. That attempt failed because /dev/sdb1 is write-protected. I got the same error message when I tried to mount it manually. How can I undo the write protection?

Comment: I've got the password for my account - the problem is that it is no longer the administrative account, and neither is any other account on the machine. sudo keeps asking me for the "root" password, and giving it my own password doesn't work anymore. Can I use this method to unlock the root account and give it a known password? If so, that would solve my problem. However, see the comment I'm posting in response to DepressedDaniel's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I then used usermod to put myself in the family group. Might I have accidentally removed myself from the sudoers list that way?

Yes. In the future, use `adduser (username) (group)` to add a group membership to a user account.

To fix this, I'd suggest booting via a live CD/USB, mounting the root partition on `/mnt`, and then:

```
chroot ./mnt adduser (username) sudo
```

to get your user account back in the `sudo` group.

Comment: The reason I couldn't get this to work is because the root partition was write-protected. The link that Karel provided mentions usingmount -rw -o remount / to remount with write permissions.

Comment: If I can use that command while following DepressedDaniel's instructions, I wouldn't need to unlock the root account, which I didn't really want to do in the first place. I won't be able to try this out for at least another 6 hours, so I'm posting this response right now, in the hopes that someone will tell me whether it should work (and if not, what I should do instead).

Comment: @JamesKuyper I've never encountered the write protection problem. It could be that your hardware is no longer allowing writes (e.g., due to SSD running out of spare blocks). One could try `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb` in case it is a setting.

Comment: I don't think it had anything to doe with a lack of spare blocks. "mount -rw -o remount /" was sufficient to solve the problem.