# SSH connection refused and user not in sudoers file

Tags: server, ssh, sudo, users

I ran `ssh localhost`, and got:

```
ssh :connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Then I tried `sudu apt-get install openshh-server`, and got:

```
user is not in the sudoers file .This incident will be reported
```

Please tell me what should be done further so that an SSH connection is established. I haven't found the solution to my problem in the previous answers. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you trying to SSH to the same host you're already logged in to?

Comment: actually I need to do that as it is required so that I can install Hadoop afterwards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you managed to mangle your group memberships so that you can't run `sudo`.  Answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) show how to fix that.  Then you can carry on with installing OpenSSH.  Good luck!

Comment: You're welcome!  If my answer has been helpful, please consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: ya sure actually the shift key is not working ,nor space nor esc key :? what can you suggest to boot ? :/