# is not in the sudoers file - problem started from one day to the other

Tags: 16.04

I run my ubuntu 16.04 for my plex media server host. Yesterday I've done a plex update as I've allways done. Today I wanted to install the todays update and suddenly I get welcomed by "is not in the sudoers file"
https://snag.gy/URMnj8.jpg

This VM has never seen anything else than plex and netdata. I've done a VM restart to no better result.

Any idea how I can get it back?

Thanks

Comment: By default, users are "in the sudoers file" either explicitly, by username, or by their membership in the `sudo` group (`id` will show which groups you're in).  Check the modification times of `/etc/groups`, `/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/sudoers.d/*`. `diff /etc/group /etc/group-`. See what has changed.

Comment: See also [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with recovery mode, how was I ment to check what has changed in the files suggested by waltinator? Just to know...

Is there any way to find out how this happend?

Thanks!