# Ubuntu root password error

Tags: 14.04, server, xubuntu

I removed a password for the viral user with this command

```
sudo passwd -d 'viral'
```

After that, I tried to login as a root user in terminal but it's asking me for a password and tells me to try again.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What are those 's? What are those suppose to do?

Comment: I am trying to do something as a root user but its ask me for a password.I couldn't do anything @Rinzwind

Comment: The root account is disabled by default on Ubuntu: see [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). If you have *also* disabled the only `sudo` account, then you will need to re-enable it from recovery mode: see for example [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/a/70445/178692)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have deleted (`-d`) the password for the user 'viral'.
So if root-login asks for password, it is as designed.

If you do `sudo passwd root` and enter new password twice as prompted, you should be able to login in terminal as root. Don't ever let root have no password, and avoid using root-login as your normal login. Almost all operations that needs root permissions can be done with `sudo`.