# My user was deleted from sudo group

Tags: permissions, sudo, password, password-recovery

I think I made a big mistake.
I did `usermod -aG docker $USER` to run docker without sudo.
After run above command, my account status like below

```
joont@joont-ununtu:~$ id
uid=1000(joont) gid=1000(joont) groups=1000(joont),999(docker)
```

Now I can't use `sudo` command through this user....
I didn't set root password after installing ubuntu.
So I don't know my root password now.
How can I recover it..?

Comment: If you *didn't* set a root password, then the method here should apply: [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/a/70445/178692)

Comment: `usermod -aG docker $USER` shouldn't remove you from your existing groups. You probably run another command as well that removed you from the existing groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add your username back to the `sudo` group, please follow the steps below:

1. Reboot your machine and hold the **<kbd>Shift</kbd>** key as soon as you pass the BIOS logo to access the GRUB boot menu. You might need to repeat this a few times until you succeed and see the boot menu.
2. Select **advanced options** and hit **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**.
3. Select the second option with **(recovery mode)** in front of it and hit **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**.
4. Wait until the machine boots and another menu appears. Choose the option with **drop to root shell prompt** in it and hit **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**.
5. Press **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** when it says **press Enter for maintenance**.
6. Once you are presented with a command prompt, write the following command and hit **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** (this will give you read and write access to your system):

   `mount -o rw,remount /`
7. Write the following command ( where `joont` is your username ) and hit **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**:

   `sudo usermod -a -G sudo joont`

   or

   `sudo adduser joont sudo`
8. Reboot your system.