# Ubuntu 20.04.1: No ability to use sudo and su

Tags: sudo, su

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I must have screwed up. I have just one user account and with this account I'm unable to use sudo and su. This obviously prevents me from running apt-get and doing other things. I've seen some posts on this - people being unable to use sudo and a workaround with su, but I can't seem to use either command. Here is what I see after issuing each command and entering the password for skip33

```
$ sudo -i
skip33 is not in the sudoers group. This incident will be reported
$ su -
su: Authentication failure
$ usermod -aG sudo skip33
usermod: Permission denied.
$ sudo su
skip33 is not in sudoers group.
```

Ok, is there any way to fix this without reinstalling the OS?

I hope to hear back from you guys. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to boot into a root shell and add your user to the sudo group - see for example [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: Thanks I just tried your suggestions in the link you provided  but I can't seem to even boot into the GRUB menu. I tried these 5 steps as well https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/key-to-show-grub-menu-ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu inside a VM, maybe that's part of the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It matters if those keypresses are being captured by the  VM Guest or not. Ensure the Guest VM is the active window.

Comment: Thanks steeldriver and user535733. You were both right.