# unable to use sudo. 21.04 I get an error is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: 21.04

I have been working on this computer all day. The hlast thing I did was to add myself to the group dialout. I logged out and came back in. I tested that I had access to the serial port and went to install an app and I got this message " is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."
I have no access to anything root related

Comment: *"I have no access to anything root related"* - if this is true then you will not be able to run any commands as root/sudo.  You need to be logged into a root account or an account in sudoers to add your user to sudoers.

Comment: You probably inadvertently removed your user from other supplemental groups (using `usermod -G` in place of `usermod -aG` for example). See [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: That is it, I did a "groups" and only see the dialout and my usergroup. everything else is gone.

Comment: Be careful with edits to sudoers file, as any error is treated as if it's a EOF (*end-of-file* marker), ie. if you accidentally introduce an error in the file, all subsequent lines will never be used; which is why the `visudo` command exists (it checks for errors before you exit). If you don't have another account with `sudo` rights (or don't have root logins enabled), you can use a *live* media to correct the issue (it's what I'd use on this box, or as my system is dual boot I could correct from the other OS).