# su: System Error, Cannot log in as root

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After installing it, the `su` command worked perfectly (I was able to log in), but after rebooting the system, whenever I run `su`, it says:

```
rakin@localhost:~$ su
Password:
su: System Error
rakin@localhost:~$
```

The user `rakin` doesn't have sudo access, so I am in big trouble. How can I fix this?

Comment: The typical Ubuntu install has no root password, and the first user gets sudo access.  You can of course change anything, but don't expect much help here with such odd configurations.

Comment: I don't recognize the error (and I can't find the string `System Error` in the source code of the `util-linux` package) however you can obtain sudo access by following the instructions here: [How do I add myself \[back\] as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)