# Get back sudo permission after accidentally commented all lines in file /etc/sudoers.d/username

Tags: permissions, sudo, password

I'm having an issue on a Ubuntu 20.04 server.

I accidentally commented out all lines in `/etc/sudoers.d/username` after reading this thread: https://superuser.com/a/1311042
because I recently noticed that I was able to run `sudo apt-get update` without being prompt for the password! Which was super strange for me, because it always asked for the password before.
But before what?
Before I actually play around with [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html) stuff, which apparently let it manage this file for running commands without being prompt for a password... something like that (I'm not an expert with that tool, I'm learning how it works actually).

But then by commenting out all lines in the `/etc/sudoers.d/username` file, I can *no more* use any `sudo <something>` command! Indeed, it now always says, e.g.:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for username: ******
username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

How could I get back to the normal behaviour on my Ubuntu user?

Comment: If you still have the `%sudo` group entry in the default `/etc/sudoers` file then it should be sufficient to add your user back to that group - see for example [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: Well, it's a headless cloud server and I'm connected to it via VPN, I guess I'm busted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, NEVER make changes to your system without understanding what they do. Sometimes the Internet is in error.

Second, if you're messing with any part of user authentication, always have a spare `root` (`sudo bash`) terminal session open, **before** you begin. I've recovered from all sorts of mistakes with this!

Now, that it's too late for these, boot from a Live USB (or your install medium, with "Try Ubuntu") and fix it from there.

Alternatively, boot into single user mode (that single user is `root`).

Finally, if it's a remote server managed by a company or an institution, kindly ask their customer service / IT department to undo the changes (it may take some time). They should normally have access to another super user or tools for such operation.