# `sudo` command isn't working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sudo

I need to install `pymol` on Ubuntu 20.04 and when I am using `sudo apt-get install -y pymol` it gives an error:

`username isn't in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The *unstated* user you are using is either (a) not in the sudoers file thus the error message, or (b) is contained in that file after an error in the file; as any errors in the file are treated as *end-of-file* thus later lines get ignored, thus why it has a special command to edit entries in it; a command that checks for errors preventing end-of-file preventing valid lines from being ignored.

Comment: [a suggested reference](https://www.tecmint.com/fix-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-the-incident-will-be-reported-ubuntu/)

Comment: Did you type "Sudo" luke you typed it in your question?

Comment: No, I've written in small letters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that the user you are using cannot use sudo because the user is not in the sudoers-file (/etc/sudoers on some systems).
So you should have another user who is in that file. It should be the one you created when you installed ubuntu.
It is possible that your sudoers-file is corrupted, then nobody is allowed to use sudo. This can happen if you don't open the sudoers-file with visudo (which is the only program you should use).
If your sudoers-file is corrupted you should do a backup and maybe reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: alright thank you lemme try