# how to create sudo password

Tags: sudo, password, username

I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.03 on to Virtual Box. I am able to log in using the created username and password.  "Sudo apt update" requests sudo password.  The initial password created on install/login password is not accepted as sudo by terminal.
"'the username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported."

Kindly advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add myself back as a sudo user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)?