sudo no longer shows user in sudoers file
Ubuntu 24.04.1
Exploring Mate User Manager and changed the Account Type to Standard just to see what it would do. The manager now cannot be unlocked with my original password.
If I try to use terminal and use sudo, it errors out saying my username is not in the sudoers file.
Where do I find the sudoers file? If I try to search for it, "No files found".
And how to edit that file to return to normal?
Thanks.
Everything I try to do rejects my password.
EDIT: Link to the suggested procedure is very old and most of the instructions simply aren't up to date with current setups (2019). My init line has extra instructions after the ro with no idea what to do with them. Nothing on the editing page says anything about saving and when I come back to look, the edits are gone. Used F10 to reboot, never used ESC. I'm just not skilled enough with Linux to make much sense out of those instructions.
EDIT(2): Reinstalled Ubuntu from the live SD as the fix.

Also asked at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/change-to-mate-user-manager-blocks-sudo-user/28532

If you don't understand the init line, then use a live USB as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/1031492/158442
